# Cloud Test integration with Jenkins

Tags: cloud, jenkins-plugins, elastest

I have Jenkins and SOASTA Cloud Test installed and now I want to integrate cloud test into Jenkins. Getting error while playing the composition from Jenkins, I have attached the screenshot. Kindly provide your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Please provide more details. Show your jenkins configuration.

Answer (score 0):

We are working in the development of [ElasTest](http://elastest.io/), which is an open source testing platform aimed to simplify the end-to-end testing processes for different types of applications, including web and mobile, among others.

The objective of ElasTest is to provide advance testing capabilities aimed to increase the scalability, robustness, security and quality of experience of
large distributed systems. Among other features, it will provide integration with Jenkins.